# Open source audio streaming server for both Window and Linux?

Tags: streaming

Is there is any open source audio streaming server available for both Windows and Linux?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems

Answer (score 0):

[Videolan](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html)